# VS2005+WinSock: warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005, winsock

I don't manage to remove a `warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch` from this code:

```
SOCKET s;
fd_set set;
FD_CLR(s,&set);
```

It seems to me that the problem is inside the implementation of VS2005's FD_CLR, and actually it's not a big issue, just quite annoying. Is there a portable equivalent version of this code that doesn't produce warnings?
(NOTE: I know that there is a #pragma to turn off the warning. I also know that the FD_CLR macro actually works perfectly. I am just looking for a way to write the code without warnings)

EDIT: Eventually, I have discovered what is going on: a third-party .h contains a (WRONG!!!) redefinition of "u_int" as "int". That's why the compiler complains for a comparison between u_int inside the FD_CLR. Shame on me.

Comment: The only possibility I see would be casting `s` to `int` (`FD_CLR( (int)s, &set );`) and see if that changes anything. Everything else would be poking around in `FD_CLR` internals, or violating its declaration (i.e., cure being worse than the illness). On second thought, you could write up a wrapper for `FD_CLR` that disables that particular warning locally.

Comment: That code looks fine, and I never had that warning about `FD_CLR` macro use in older or newer versions of VS. Are you sure that is the line the error is about?

Comment: @DevSolar Changing the type of "s" doesn't solve. Unfortunately the problem is inside the macro. But writing a wrapper for FD_CLR is a clean solution, bonus for you if you post it as true answer.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg yes, tested also with a tree-line test program. It probably depends on the VS2005 SP level (mine is 2.0.50727 SP2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disabling the warning globally, or locally every time you call `FD_CLR()`, perhaps write a wrapper for that call that disables that particular warning locally for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rewrite the macro FD_CLR and modify loop variable's int/uint, but it leads to a macro redefinition warning. I think #pragma is better.